# How to check with regexp that first 2 characters can be letters or digits, but other characters only digits

Tags: regex

How to check with regexp that first 2 characters can be letters or digits, but other characters only digits?

```
Valid:
123456
AA123456
A123456

Not valid:
AAA
AAA123456
```

Tried `/^[a-zA-Z][0-9]{2}[\d]$/i` but it does not work,

please advice

Comment: What language/tool are you working with, by the way?

Comment: PHP, just checking input field. By regexp is so hard to learn? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using character classes (`[..]`) correctly. Use this:

```
/^\w{2}\d+$/
```

You don't need *both* `[a-zA-Z]` and the `i` "Ignore case" flag, you can use either method.
But there is no need to construct a class: `\w` is the shortcut for "any *word* character" -- `a..z,A..Z,0..9`, plus (thanks, Arshajii) the `_` character. If that last one is not allowed, use `[A-Z\d]`.

Since after the first two classes only any number of digits may follow, you can use `\d+` -- no need to wrap it into a character class of its own. The class version would be `[0-9]` but again, there is the shortcut `\d` for that.

Comment: Alphanumeric != word. `\w` includes underscores as well.

Comment: @arshajii: Always forget about that one. Edited my answer to point this out.

Comment: If you replace `\w` with `[A-Z]` then your regex will make the 2 letters mandatory for it to match;

Answer (score 4):

You've split up the first part into two character classes (`[a-zA-Z]` and `[0-9]`) and the `{2}` quantifier is only applying to the second. Try this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}\d*
```

Comment: Better still, get rid of the `a-z` and use the `/i` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, I think the most elegant regex would be this:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{0,2}[\d]+$
```

Also depends how many digits are mandatory after the 2 letters (replace `+` with `*`if `AA` is a valid string).

Comment: first 2 characters can be letters or digits, but other only digits.

Comment: so this matches what you need then :)